# CRAN example fails if run offline (talks to external API)

Tags: r

I have a roxygen code block with an example that talks to an external API. It looks something like this

```
#' @examples
#' library(opentriviadb)
#' dat <- httr::GET("https://opentdb.com/api_category.php")
```

The problem I have is that this works fine with an internet connection, but if CRAN builds this while a machine doesn't have access to internet, it will fail R CMD CHECK with

```
Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
  Timeout was reached: [opentdb.com] Operation timed out after 10000 milliseconds with 0 out of 0 bytes received
```

Is there someway I can skip examples being run if offline? I know you can wrap code with `\dontrun{}` but CRAN generally discourages this if there is a better alternative. Is there a better way to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is.  If you already use the `curl` package, you can rely on its function `has_internet()`:

```
> curl::has_internet() 
[1] TRUE
>
```

We used that recently in package [gtrendsR](http://cloud.r-project.org/package=gtrendsR) which, for obvious reasons, cannot query Google much without a connection...  And while thinking about that I realized that I had also implemented my own test in my own utility package [dang](https://cloud.r-project.org/package=dang)

```
> dang::isConnected()
[1] TRUE
>
```

which [does not depend on any other packages](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/dang/blob/master/R/isConnected.R) so you could copy it (and attribution is always appreciated):

```
isConnected <- function(site="https://www.google.com") {
    uoc <- function(site) {
        con <- url(site)                # need to assign so that we can close
        open(con)                       # in case of success we have a connection
        close(con)                      # ... so we need to clean up
    }
    suppressWarnings(!inherits(try(uoc(site), silent=TRUE), "try-error"))
}
```

Comment: Thanks Dirk. I modified my roxygen block to be
```
#' @examples
#' library(opentriviadb)
#' if (dang::isConnected()){
#'    cats <- httr::GET("https://opentdb.com/api_category.php")
#' }
```

But this still fails with `Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
    Could not resolve host: opentdb.com`

Comment: Of course if you call `dang::isConnected()` you depends on `dang`.  Also, maybe you should make the argument `https://opentdb.com` to have it error if that does not resolve.

Comment: Yep, changing the `site` argument has made things work as expected. Thanks a lot Dirk!

Comment: And yeah, just took the dependency for testing - I'll copy the function over with attribution and remove the dependency when I resubmit.